# How do I allow higher function keys (F13-F24) in Vim?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal

My vim sessions use `term=win32` and my F13-24 keys do not work, but they are permitted I believe from checking `:help t_ku`. I've gained shallow insight on how to connect vim keycodes to term keys via "escape sequences" but I've reached a deadlock on identifying what `<ce>` represents, as all the `Fn` keys always start with it, e.g., when doing `:set termcap`, I would see `<F1>` assigned to `<ce>^C;`, `<F2>` to `<ce>^C<`, and `<F11>` to `<ce>^C<85>`.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) In order to reproduce your problem it would be nice if you could share your Operating System version (e.g. Windows 10, Linux Ubuntu 22.04, macOS X, ...) and the terminal you are using (e.g.  `cmd`, `conemu`, `tmux`, `kitty`, ...)

Comment: Let's keep experimenting: in insert mode press `<C-v>` followed by one of the working function keys. It should insert a *literal* `<ce>something` where `<ce>` is treated as one special character. Then move your cursor on `<ce>` and do `ga` to display the codes of that character in various formats. See `:help ga`. FWIW, on unix systems, that leader key is usually `^[`, for `<esc>`.

Comment: Could you tell us what do you mean by F13 is Shift-F1?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Windows 10 is my OS, the term uses win32 with pwsh as the shell.

Comment: @romainl Thanks for the `ga` feature, however instead of displaying the proper escape sequence I only see the last character prepended with `Î`, e.g., `<F1>` -> `Î;`. `ga` on the character prints `<Î> 206, Hex 00ce, Oct 316, Digr I>` I'm assuming the escape sequence literally is `Î`, as `<ce>` seems to be the UTF+16 hex code.

Comment: Thanks for the shell. I understand that you are using Powershell. But I'm still wondering what are F13 to F24. I only have on my keyboard F1 to F12 that I can combine with Shift and Ctrl. Do you really have a F13 to F24 keys on your keyboard?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Only a few keyboards are made with them, I have a split keyboard that switches profiles containing keys. I'm preserving the standard Fn keys (which includes modifiers) for compiling, testing, buffer/arglist commands so I would like to make use of 13-24.

Comment: Did some testing, `<C-V><F3>` puts `Î=`. Recording `<F3>` to macro and pasting via register puts `<80>k3`. With the `:set` command, I tried variations: `:set <F3>=\<Î>=`, `:set <F3>=<Î=>`, `:set <F3>=<C-v><F3>`, `:set <F3>=<C-v>128k3` where `128` is the decimal of `<80>`. None worked.